# How to remove only the left axis labels in R cdplot?

Tags: r, graphics

The attached example produces a conditional density plot.  In the example, I can use `ylab = NA` to remove the "x" axis label and if I use `yaxlabels = "n"` both the left and right tick labels are removed.

How can I suppress only the left labels (i.e. "0" and "1") and keep the right-hand probability scale?

```
# Example
Forest = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1)
change = c(-1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 6)
mydata = data.frame(Forest,change)

x = factor(mydata$Forest)

cdplot(x~mydata$change, ylab = NA, xlab = NA)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, you can use `yaxlabels = "n"` to remove the y-labels on both sides. 
Than just add the right side axis back via `axis(4)`.

```
Forest = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1)
change = c(-1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 6)
mydata = data.frame(Forest,change)

x = factor(mydata$Forest)

cdplot(x~mydata$change, ylab = NA, xlab = NA, yaxlabels = "n")
axis(4)
```

[image]